# how to load a dialog exe as a child window in anohter dialog process

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I have two separate apps **A.exe** and **B.exe**, which results into two independent top level windows. Both are C++ Apps and uses win32 gui framework on windows platform. I want to combine these to a new app **C.exe** such that it shows the two in separate tabs in a multi tab dialog.

Baiscaly how to set Dialog `Dlg1` in **C.exe** as parent window to A.exe's(Top Level Window) or in other way how to load A.exe(Top level Window) as a child window in `Dlg1` in **C.exe**

Is there any solution to it using win32 or MFC? Or it is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

If C.exe spawns A.exe and B.exe, it could pass its own `HWND` as a command-line parameter, then A.exe and B.exe can retreive that parameter and use that `HWND` as the parent window in calls to `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetParent()` whenever needed.  Otherwise, C.exe will have to use `FindWindow/Ex()` or `EnumWindows()` to manually find the `HWND` handles of A.exe and B.exe and then call `SetParent()` on them.